# Fatal error: Call to a member function db() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, database, class

any one help with this error please

**Fatal error: Call to a member function db() on a non-object**

```
in /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/...../shop/inc/db/db.class.php on line 8
```

here is my code

```
<?php


switch ($db_type) {
    case "mysql":
        require_once($includepath . "db/mysql.php");
}
$Var_144->db($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_db, false);
$db = $Var_144;
if (!$db->db_connect_id) {
    site_error("Can not connect to database");
}
?>
```

here is the error link

```
$Var_144->db($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_db, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's saying that `$Var_144` is not an object. make sure that `$Var_144` is initialized before the `db()` call.

Comment: I can't give example code, you need to show more code. basicly, there needs to be a $Var_144 = /*something*/ before that command. right now $Var_144 is not set, thus that error is coming up.